# AWS Lambda Function URL Event Type

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

What is the exact event type from the @types/aws-lambda package for a Lambda function hosted using function URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Lambda Function URL request and response events use the [Amazon API Gateway payload format version 2.0](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html#http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.proxy-format).

The corresponding TypeScript types are `APIGatewayProxyEventV2` (request) and `APIGatewayProxyResultV2<T>` (response) in the [@types/aws-lambda](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/aws-lambda/trigger/api-gateway-proxy.d.ts) package.

```js
/**
 * Works with HTTP API integration Payload Format version 2.0
 * @see - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html
 */
export type APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2<T = never> = Handler<APIGatewayProxyEventV2, APIGatewayProxyResultV2<T>>;
```

Comment: Thanks. What about the type for the handler?

Comment: @RajChaudhary Glad to help.  See the code block.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET, following request and response objects are used when using Lambda with Function URLs.

- [APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest.cs)
- [APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse.cs)

You can find similar in typescript.

Probably `APIGatewayEventRequestContextV2` should be the respective one. Anyway, you can explore all the available types here at [api-gateway-proxy.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/aws-lambda/trigger/api-gateway-proxy.d.ts).

Comment: I use `AWSLambda.APIGatewayProxyEventV2` for JS.